# create pdf table within the pdf cell using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to create a pdftable with in the pdf cell. i was so trouble to create it.Please help me to create it ..

This is my partial code:

```
maintable = new PdfPTable(1);
        empdetright = new PdfPTable(9);
        maintable.TotalWidth = 310f;
        maintable.LockedWidth = true;

        int[] rightTblWidth= { 8, 8, 10,10,10,10,10,10,15};
        empdetright.SetWidths(rightTblWidth);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Month", fnt1));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        empdetright.AddCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Amount of Wages Rs.", fnt1));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        empdetright.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Contribution", fnt1));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.Colspan = 4;
        empdetright.AddCell(cell);

        ( I want to create a table with in the Contribution cell )   

        //cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(":", fnt1));
        //cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        //empdetright.AddCell(cell);
        //cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("::", fnt1));
        //cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        //empdetright.AddCell(cell);
        //cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(":::", fnt1));
        //cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        //empdetright.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Refund of Advances", fnt1));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        empdetright.AddCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Non cont. services from ----- To----", fnt1));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        empdetright.AddCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Remarks", fnt1));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        empdetright.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(empdetright);
        maintable.AddCell(cell);
        doc.Add(maintable);
```

I was merge four column with name contribution. but i just need a pdf table with three column in this cell.How can i create it. please help me to create it...